# Opencart 3 - display custom fields on register email to admin

Tags: php, custom-fields, opencart-3

I've created a couple custom fields on opencart 3 for new account registrations.

However the notification I get for new customers registration doesn't include the custom fields created.

I believe I need to edit catalog/controler/mail/register.php
somewhere over here... any one has an idea on how to get it done correctly?

```
$data['email'] = $args[0]['email'];
$data['telephone'] = $args[0]['telephone'];

    ///

$this->load->model('account/custom_field');

    ///
```

Comment: all custom fields filled by customer are displayed in Admin-> Order history-> Additional tab...  so you need to look at corresponding files how this are achieved and use this... Of course if you are coder

Comment: Thanks K.B. however the registration is not an order. customers can just create an account and not order anything. so the custom fields data will not be stored under orders.

Comment: But you can use this logic how to get info from database and place where you need. Custom fields are stored to address table... in json format.